# Angularjs scope var in template of custom directive

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive

I have a custom directive hello

```
myapp.directive('hello', function() {
 return {
link : function (scope, elem, attr) {
    scope.url = attr.url;
    console.log(scope.url);
},
template: '<div ng-include="\'[{url}]\'"></div>'
};
});
```

my html code is

```
<div url="mypage.html"></div>
```

I get the value mypage.html in my console.log but is not able to include the page it says

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/[%7Burl%7D]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to sanitize the html before binding it to ng-include, but below is the alternate solution to your problem you are facing

```
          app.directive('widget', function(){
            return {
                scope: {
                  url: '@'
                },
                template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>',                   
                controller: function($scope) {
                  $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
                      console.log($scope.url)
                      return $scope.url
                  }
                }
            }
        })
```

HTML Code

```
<div url="mypage.html"></div>
```